# Passing a variable to a docker build script

Tags: docker, variables, environment-variables

I am trying to pass a variable to a simple docker script

I tried the method described [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/).

```
FROM golang:latest

ARG buildtime_variable=default_value 

ENV env_var_name=$buildtime_variable

RUN echo $env_var_name
```

I tried building it with

> docker build --build-arg buildtime_variable=a_value .

And I get the results

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
>
> Step 1/4 : FROM golang:latest  ---> da66b002dd02
>
> Step 2/4 : ARG buildtime_variable=default_value  ---> Running in
>   91055d467539  Removing intermediate container 91055d467539  --->
>   1241ad5c9f12
>
> Step 3/4 : ENV env_var_name=$buildtime_variable  ---> Running in
>   c61292041ccf  Removing intermediate container c61292041ccf  --->
>   4eeac4402f5b
>
> Step 4/4 : RUN echo $env_var_name  ---> Running in 80ba16d2ee9c 
>   Removing intermediate container 80ba16d2ee9c  ---> b814420cc448
>   Successfully built b814420cc448

I was expecting it to echo a_value, instead it does no such thing, its like the variable didn't get correctly transmitted.

I tried it with `RUN echo A`
which produced the expected result of echoing A

Is it time to use an env-file? or do I not need to resort to that?

**EDIT**

Just did an update, my version info is

> docker version Client: Docker Engine - Community  Version:
>   18.09.2  API version:       1.39  Go version:        go1.10.8  Git commit:        6247962  Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019 
>   OS/Arch:           windows/amd64  Experimental:      false
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Community  Engine:   Version:          18.09.2
>   API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)   Go version:
>   go1.10.6   Git commit:       6247962   Built:            Sun Feb 10
>   04:28:48 2019   OS/Arch:          windows/amd64   Experimental:
>   false

**EDIT**

I just tried switching to Linux containers and trying an example from [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables)

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG CONT_IMG_VER
ENV CONT_IMG_VER v1.0.0
RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
```

> docker build --build-arg CONT_IMG_VER=v2.0.1 .

This actually prints out a value!

unfortunately this is the default value `v1.0.0` instead of the variable defined by `--build-arg`

Also, I need this to work with a windows container.

Comment: Am I the only one with this problem? Does anyone else get the same problem?

Comment: The same code is working for me. Can you tell me your docker version

Comment: I tried installing docker on a new machine, still got the same problem.

Comment: @ManishDash You mean it prints "a_value" for you?

Comment: I'm using windows containers if that makes a difference

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5089

Comment: yes it prints the a_value at Step 4 when I build. I am on MacOS with docker ver 18

Comment: I can get it to print a_value when I run this on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not addressing the actual question, but I feel it solves the problem using the recommended way of *dockerising*.

As I understand your need, you want to specify an environment variable *before* building the container and want this varible to be there whenever you start the container.

You can do this using docker-compose. There we can specify an .env file containing all the environment variables we want.

Create a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: golang:latest
    container_name: golang_app
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    command: ping -t localhost
```

Create a `variables.env` file in the same folder with contents:

```
env_var_name=a_value
```

You can run the container as `docker-compose up`.

Now if you go inside the container using `docker exec -it golang_app cmd` and <strike>type `echo $env_var_name` you should see `a_value`</strike>.

**Edit**: On windows env variables are accessed as %var%. So try `echo %env_var_name%` inside the container.

`SET` gives the list of all env variables. You can see that `env_var_name` is listed with the value of `a_value`.

Comment: So is this enough for your task?

Comment: great idea, but unfortunately on windows this just prints $env_var_name

Comment: Switched to windows containers for the first time to figure this out. Got it working !

Comment: ok, so this sounds like a windows specific problem, it works when I use ubuntu, it works when you use windows containers on macos, it doesn't work when I use windows containers on windows. Its starting to look like I should submit a bug report and script a work around for my case until the bug is fixed. Thanks, this information helped :)